# java Why file size is different with operation system

Tags: java

I download file from website and check the size (the same if i check size in operation system in bytes).

```
        connection.getContentLength();
        int sizeBefore = connection.getContentLength();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        File destFile = new File(destFileName);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(destFile));

        while ((i = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(i);               
        }
        long sizeAfter = destFile.length(); 
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedInputStream.close();

        if (sizeAfter == sizeBefore) {
            log.debug("Downloaded file correct");
        }
```

then I tryed check stored file by other way too (NIO):

```
long size =  Files.size(destFile.toPath())));
```

The result is different with size from operation system.Why?

Comment: How did you download? Was getContentLength larger? That could mean, that the download code should be inspected. With FTP there could be conversions of CR/CRLF happening

Comment: getContentLength() was larger

Comment: I probably misunderstood, but _after_ closing the written file, you take the file size? As insufficient was written I would like to see the writing code.

Comment: I have edited,you can see code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the file size before closing stream. I you do after closing streams you will get the same size with operation system

```
    connection.connect();
    int sizeBefore =  connection.getContentLength();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    File destFile = new File (destFileName);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(destFile));
    while ((i = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(i);
    }
    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
    bufferedInputStream.close();
    long sizeAfter = destFile.length();
    if (sizeAfter==sizeBefore) {
        log.info("Downloaded correct");                
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Binary prefixes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Adoption_by_IEC_and_NIST

Windows uses 1024 bytes in a kilobyte (2^10) while Linux uses 1000 bytes in a kilobyte. This propagates in MB, GB, etc...

Comment: Sounds good but only relevant when reporting the size not in bytes without any prefix. Was this the case here?

Comment: I didn't ask about difference between calculation size in operation system.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
    long sizeAfter = destFile.length(); 
    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
    bufferedInputStream.close();
```

should be

```
    bufferedOutputStream.close(); // Close the file. Flushes too.
    bufferedInputStream.close();
    long sizeAfter = destFile.length(); // Check its size on disk.
```

Especially a BufferedOutputStream will write its buffer only when entirely filled.
The last buffer is most often actually written on `close()` calling `flush()`.